# How do you disable tooltips in ember-cli-chart?

Tags: ember.js, chart.js

I am using ember-cli-chart which is a wrapper for chart js. I am trying to disable the tooltips.

I have tried the following code but it does nothing:

```
chartData: computed('model', function() {
    return {
      labels: ['1', '2'],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Example Label',
          data: [this.model.example1, this.model.example2],
          options: {
            tooltips: {
              enabled: false,
            }
          }
      }]
    }
  }),
```

Why does this not disable the tooltips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/hashicorp/atlas/blame/c44f7af5d63ab2c89a669d29bdfcc86ffb01bac9/frontend/atlas/app/routes/v2/settings/tokens.js) for `ember-cli-chart` shows this example usage:

```
{{ember-chart
  type=CHARTTYPE
  data=CHARTDATA
  options=CHARTOPTIONS
  width=CHARTWIDTH
  height=CHARTHEIGHT
  plugins=CHARTPLUGINS
  customLegendElement=CUSTOMLEGENDELEMENT
}}
```

You need to define `options` as a separate property that’s passed in when invoking the chart component.